# MongoDB Aggregate query to calculate ARPU When User and Payment Model are separated

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, average

I want to write an aggregate query to calculate ARPU (Average Revenue Per User) but I'm stuck on how to use data from to separate models, I know that I can join to models using `$lookup` but I cannot get count of all users in this way.

These are my models:

```
// User:
{
    _id,
    username: String,
    os: String
}
```

and

```
// Payment:
{
    _id,
    user: ObjectId,
    price: Number
}
```

I need to calculate sum of all payments divided by count of all users.

After that I need to group them by OS, i.e. sum of all payments made by users who have `os='os1'` divided by count of all users who have `os='os1'` for each OS

#### EDIT

for example, sample data for User is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b77fdffcbbd830011dbc04e"),
    "username" : "user1",
    "os" : "android"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7856756aaf56001120816b"),
    "username" : "user2",
    "os" : "android"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b824fa7234d1b0010310522"),
    "username" : "user3",
    "os" : "android"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8a242444074c0074b8a318"),
    "username" : "user4",
    "os" : "ios"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7801b0cbbd830011dbc050"),
    "username" : "user5",
    "os" : "ios"
}
```

and sample data for Payment is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bab61b617df7f173037fb1b"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5b77fdffcbbd830011dbc04e"), // user1
    "price" : 5
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bad4f980ab23100119300ec"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5b77fdffcbbd830011dbc04e"), // user1
    "price" : 10
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bad525edeed4e0011286842"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5b7856756aaf56001120816b"), // user2
    "price" : 5
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bad525edeed4e0011286848"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5b8a242444074c0074b8a318"), // user4
    "price" : 5
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bad525edeed4e0011286849"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5b8a242444074c0074b8a318"), // user4
    "price" : 15
}
```

My expected output is a Number that is achieved using aggregate query.

Initially what I want is Average Revenue Per User:

**ARPU:** `{sum of all payments} / {count of all users} = 40 / 5 = 8`

If I can achieve that, then I need to group them for each OS:

**ios-ARPU:** `{sum of payments ios users made} / {count of ios users} = 20 / 2 = 10`

**android-ARPU:** `{sum of payments android users made} / {count of android usrs} = 20 / 3 = 6.67`

- Note that some users may not make any payments but they need to be counted in calculating ARPU.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done already?

Comment: @chridam I have no Idea what I should do, I'm familiar with MongoDB aggregates quite well, but I don't have a solution for this problem.
it is possible to do two separate queries and divide the results in a higher level language like node, but I need this for metabase so I need it to be one query, and I don't know how to merge results of queries on two models in one query.

Comment: @chridam I have googled a lot to see if there is something to union two collections or run an aggregate query on more than one collection or even add a collection in a stage of aggregate pipeline but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: @MohammadGanji could you edit your post and paste few sample documents with expected output ?

Comment: @mickl I added sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and then use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to calculate `totalPayments` per user. Then you can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `null` to get single document with total number of users and total payments. To get ARPU you need [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html) in last step.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "payments",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "user",
            as: "payments"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            os: 1,
            totalPayments: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$payments",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                        $add: [ "$$value", "$$this.price" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            totalUsers: { $sum: 1 },
            totalPayments: { $sum: "$totalPayments" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            arpu: { $divide: [ "$totalPayments", "$totalUsers" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Outputs: `{ "arpu" : 8 }`

To get arpu per os you just need to `$group` by `$os`:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$os",
        totalUsers: { $sum: 1 },
        totalPayments: { $sum: "$totalPayments" }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
{ "_id" : "ios", "arpu" : 10 }
{ "_id" : "android", "arpu" : 6.666666666666667 }
```

Comment: this answer was clever, I like the way you think! starting from users and bringing all purchases with a lookup not in a normal way!
but isn't it going to be slow for a huge number of users?

Answer (score 1):

Leverage the use of **[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)** to get both set of calculations in one pipeline after the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** stage.

The following demonstrates the use of **[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)** for the above aggregate operation:

```
db.getCollection('Payment').aggregate([
    { "$lookup": { 
        "from": "users",
        "localField": "user",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "user"
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "user": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$user", 0] }
    } },
    { "$facet": {
        "users": [
            { "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "ARPU": { "$avg": "$price" }
            } }
        ],
        "os": [
            { "$group": {
                "_id": "$user.os",
                "ARPU": { "$avg": "$price" }
            } },
            { "$group": {
                "_id": null,
                "avgs": {
                    "$push": {
                        "k": { "$concat": ["ARPU", "-", "$_id"] },
                        "v": "$ARPU"
                    }
                } 
            } },
            { "$replaceRoot": {
                "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$avgs" }
            } }
        ]
    } }
])
```

This will yield for the given sample docs:

```
{
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "ARPU" : 8.0
        }
    ],
    "os" : [ 
        {
            "ios-ARPU" : 10.0,
            "android-ARPU" : 6.66666666666667
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what happens when you use $group with null??
and how does this solution counts all users, even those who do not have any payments? can you please explain?

Comment: The `_id` field is mandatory; however, you can specify an `_id` value of null to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole. The solution is calculating averages by using the mongo native `$avg` operator without having to calculate the total and then dividing to get the average; `{sum of all payments} / {count of all users}` is simply the average of all the payments made by all users.

Comment: Thanks about the _id, but when you use $lookup in payments, you bring users who have a payment, not all of them